# Can't insert to database using jsf and hibernate. Object return null

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have problem with my code that about insert new record to database. Here is my code. Hope anyone suggest me.

**Customer**

```
public class Customer  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private int cusId;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String email;
     private Serializable dob;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(int cusId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Serializable dob) {
       this.cusId = cusId;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.email = email;
       this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int getCusId() {
        return this.cusId;
    }

    public void setCusId(int cusId) {
        this.cusId = cusId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Serializable getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Serializable dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

**customerBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="customerBean")
@RequestScoped
public class customerBean implements Serializable {

    private Customer selectedCustomer;
    private List<Customer> customer;

    /** Creates a new instance of customerBean */
    public customerBean() {
        selectedCustomer = new Customer();
        customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        CustomersDao cust_dao = new CustomersDao();
        customer = cust_dao.findAll();
        return customer;
    }

    public Customer getSelectedCustomer() {
        return selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void setSelectedCustomer(Customer selectedCustomer) {
        this.selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void btnCreate(){
        CustomersDao cust_create = new CustomersDao();
        String msg;
        if(cust_create.createCustomer(selectedCustomer)){
            msg = "Created Successfully!";
        }else{
            msg = "Error. Please check again!";
        }
        FacesMessage massage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, massage);
    }
}
```

**CustomersDao**

```
public class CustomersDao {
    public boolean createCustomer(Customer customer){
        boolean flag;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(customer);
            session.beginTransaction().commit();
            flag = true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            flag = false;
            session.beginTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

**xhtml**

```xml
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="btnCreate" oncomplete="createDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Create" value="New Customer" update=":formCreate" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="formCreate">
    <p:dialog header="Create New Customer" widgetVar="createDialog" resizable="false" id="createDlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">

            <h:outputText value="First Name: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.firstName}"/>

            <h:outputText value="Last Name: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.lastName}" />

            <h:outputText value="DOB: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.dob}" />

            <h:outputText value="Email: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.email}" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:separator />
                <p:commandButton id="btnOK" oncomplete="createDialog.hide()" immediate="true" action="#{customerBean.btnCreate}" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Save" value="Save" update=":formData, :msgs" />
                <p:commandButton id="btnCancel" oncomplete="createDialog.hide()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

When I running my code in Debug Mode, values which I entered such as first name, lasst name, dob, email are return **null**. I tried change to SessionScope but nothing change. I'm using PrimesFace 3.5, Glassfish 3.1, Hibernate and JSF 2.0

Comment: I think you wanted to put that immediate="true" on the CANCEL button, not on the OK button.

Comment: @Gimby Now i can receive value I entered but custId still is 0, custId is the identity field, why this happened?

Comment: Because you have a mistake in either your database or your hibernate configuration for the Customer entity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `immediate` attribute is abused in your save button. Just remove it to let JSF lifecycle happen the ordinary way.

Secondly, your cancel button doesn't invoke any server-side action, so let it become a plain push button by switching to `<p:button>`, or defining `type="button"` on your `<p:commandButton>`.

Lastly, you begin a **new transaction thrice**. Remove the second and third invocation from `session.beginTransaction()` to `session.getTransaction()`, otherwise you're thrashing an old transaction (and not committing it).

Comment: thank you for supporting. I removed immediate attribute and i can receive value that entered. But when I check with debug mode, cusId still is 0, in MySQL it is identity column and i have one record with identity 2, it should be 3 if i insert to database. Why this happened?

Comment: Be sure to read on what's the deference between transient, detached and persistent entity states. You're basically trying to merge the detached entity thus making it persistent and it seems like you want to persist a transient entity according to your comment.

Comment: Your selected prefix to the customer instance is ambiguos. Try to express in clear terms what you're trying to achieve. It seems that you're pasting the part of the code so the full context is unclear. Apart from that your usage of JSF principles is wrong and you don't follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: i mean that custId is identity column.